# How to read data from JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can receive the response in JSON, but I am not able to read it. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/BindDatatable",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(data.d[i].name);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: well in your loop you loop through the data but trying to read data.d[i]. just add "debugger;" in your success function and hit f12 check the structure of you data.

Comment: i have add it but it is not working

Comment: here is my json response

Comment: what do u see alert!

Comment: "d":[{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":1,"name":"mks","email":"aa@gmail.com","age":22},{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":2,"name":"pawan","email":"pp@gmail.com","age":23},{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":3,"name":"hfg","email":"hfh@gmail.com","age":23},{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":4,"name":"fsdaf","email":"fdsa@gmail.com","age":56},{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":5,"name":"hfgmm","email":"gd","age":122},{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails",

Comment: @Kishore i want to alert my name field

Comment: @ManojSharma do you want to iterate over the values in array "d" ? In that case the `for` loop condition should be `data.d.length`

Comment: @ManojSharma: Welcome to [so]! If you want to add more information to your question, you can edit your question instead of posting it in the comments so that it can be formatted properly.

Comment: @Kishore Can you explain why we use d ?

Comment: public static List<UserDetails> BindDatatable() { var dt = new DataTable(); List<UserDetails> details = new List<UserDetails>();
using (SqlConnection con = "connti") {using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("qry, con)){ con.Open(); SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); adp.Fill(dt);foreach (DataRow tdrow in dt.Rows)
{UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
                    user.id = Convert.ToUInt16(tdrow["Id"]);
                  
                    details.Add(user); }}}return details.ToList(); }

Comment: This is my working code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $.ajax, try using $.getJSON, or use JSON.parse(data) when data comes,
The actual problem is with JSON data, you need to convert it into JavaScript object to use it.
Once it parse and converts into JavaScript Object, you can Access like data.d[i].name

Comment: $.getJSON is a wrapper around $.ajax, which is limited.

Comment: yes, $.getJSON is limited to JSON request only but it automatically converts JSON to javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand in your case you are getting **JSON Object** in variable **data** in method **success** then and you json format is this

> "d":[{"__type":"_Default+UserDetails","id":1,"name":"mks","email":"aa@gmail.com",‌​"age":22}]

then you just have to change the following condition

```
success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            alert(data.d[i].name);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thank sir. Can you tell me why we use d ?

Comment: @ManojSharma: did you create the JSON file yourself?

Comment: As your **JSON** starts with a key **"d"** that contains the serialized object array of values. The length of the **data** variable in **success** is **1** and that does not contains the actual value we needed.That's why i had used **data.d.length**.